# How to use logback in a PlayFramework project

Tags: playframework, slf4j, logback, playframework-1.x

Because of dependencies on a project I am working on developing a web application using the Play!Framework, I have to configure logback to prevent it from flooding my output with DEBUG messages.
But as log4j is the default log library used by the Play!Framework, I don't really know how to make it consider a logback.xml configuration file.

The best would be to make the Play!Framework completely use logback/Slf4j instead of log4j. How could I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment play1 use log4j or juli (I'm not sure if juli works, but the code exists). There is [feature-request](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/673-feature-request-use-logbackslf4j-instead-of-log4j), but unfortunately you can't use logback correctly if you have a single Logger.class. In this case %F and all other uppercase chars from [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout) which is discussed [here](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/98713420ae8fd3aa/2c070cb94a893f85#2c070cb94a893f85).

**Update**: After some information from Ceki, I have now the knowledge how it can fixed in a clean way. So the feature-request can implemented in a clean way.

An idea could be to let log4j write to logback, if it will possible. 
Furthermore I'm thinking about creating a patch which solve this issue. So I don't want to start until this is fixed and I get some signals from the core-team that they accept any re-factoring at such a central class.

To make a long story short: At the moment it's impossible without hacking the framework.
However I don't understand your problem. What do you want to do that log4j can't? Perhaps you could explain your root cause in another question.

Comment: I must agree with the last part of Niels' post. What do you want to do what log4j can't?

Comment: @Ceki: Logback have made some improvements, but I can't find a must have. And again: log4j can be extended/wrapped logback not.

Comment: @niels Since logback-classic exposes its API via SLF4J, you would probably want to extend org.slf4j.Logger. See the org.slf4j.ext package for extension examples. The http://slf4j.org/xref/org/slf4j/ext/LoggerWrapper.html class should be
particularly helpful. See also XLogger and XLoggerFactory in the same package. The key here is to invoke LocationAwareLogger when you can, i.e. when one of log4j, jul and logback is the backend. Anyway, I think the play.Logger class could wrap org.slf4j.Logger if that is what you wanted.

Comment: I don't "want" to use logback, I just "have to", because of maven dependencies on this project.

At the moment, logback lib is automatically imported into the lib folder since it is the log lib in use in this project. It makes his own life without taking care of what log4j is writing in parralel, resulting a huge mess of logs.

For me log4j is just fine, but I have to deal with logback :/

I am not really an expert in that matter, until now writting a log.properties file just did what I needed.

Comment: @Claw: Sorry then I don't have a solution. I assume that play will support slf4j directly in plays Logger, but this will be only a solution in the future (Follow http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/673 for this). At the moment you can only try to remove the dependency from logback. So you must learn the maven magic, to remove the dependency.

Comment: tons of projects/libraries are using logback so it is unfortunate that those cannot be brought into playframework  in a clean way because it is using the outdated log4j project(ie. the log4j lead went and created slf4j so log4j is kinda dead)

Comment: You must be talking about Play 1? Play 2 uses logback by default.

Comment: Yes I changed the tags and the answers to make it clear. You can see it if you look at the date of the answer.